# Make Array Of The Same Key From An Array

Tags: php, mysql

[Image Attach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytxEr.png)

i have mysql array

I want to make array of same key Type like to fill in multi axis graph
which requires of this type

name: 'Email',
type: 'column',
data: [1.4, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.8, 3.8, 4.6]
}, {
name: 'Web',
type: 'column',
data: [1.1, 3, 3.1, 4, 4.1, 4.9, 6.5, 8.5]
}

Like this
so i need to make array of the same key type from mysql array list like

```
array(
'name'=>'Email'
'type'=>'column',
'data'=>['1,2,3,4'] // list of all array of the same key Type (Web or Email)
);
```

Please Help Thanks.

```
  ^ array:8 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Email"
    "data" => "16"
    
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Email"
    "data" => "158"
    
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Web"
    "data" => "17"
   
  ]
 3 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Web"
    "data" => "17"
    
  ]
]
```

array i am getting from mysql

Comment: just fetch the values from the database, then group the array accordingly based on what your graph plugin requires. you need some code to do that though

Comment: Please add a sample of the mysql array you mentioned so we can help you. I looks like you just need a simple algorithm to convert the mysql array to a new format

Answer (score 0):

To solve you issue you need to loop the result from the query and create a new array with the desired format `[{name'=>'Email','type'=>'column','data'=>['1,2,3,4']}, {...}]`. There are several ways of solving this but I will describe a simple algorithm so you understand what to do.

```
  $mysqlResult = [["name" => "Email", "data" => "16"],
              ["name" => "Web", "data" => "17"],  
              ["name" => "Email", "data" => "23"]];

  $expectedResult = [];

  /*First we loop the mysql result mapping it to a dictionary where the keys of the dictionary is the `name`. This way we will be able to append all the `data` column values*/
  foreach($mysqlResult as $result) {
    $key = $result['name'];

    /*We verify if the key does not exists already in expected result array. If the key does not exists we add it do the expected array.*/
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $expectedResult)) {
      $expectedResult[$key] = ['name' => $result['name'], 'type'=> 'column'];
    }
    
    /*We push the data column value to the data field that is going to store columns data.*/
    $expectedResult[$key]['data'][] = $result['data'];
  }
  
  print_r($expectedResult);
```

The code above give us the following result:

```
 Array
(
    [Email] => Array
        (
            [name] => Email
            [type] => column
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16
                    [1] => 23
                )

        )

    [Web] => Array
        (
            [name] => Web
            [type] => column
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 17
                )
        )
)
```

Note that the field `data` is an array of elements and we want it to be an array with a single string separating all the elements by a comma like this['1,2,3,4']. To achieve that we loop the dictionary using the PHP [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function:

```
  foreach ($expectedResult as $key => $value) {
      $expectedResult[$key]['data'] = [implode (',', $expectedResult[$key]['data'])];
  }
```

Now we just need to extract the values from the expected result since it is a dictionary:

```
  $expectedResult = array_values($expectedResult);

  print_r($expectedResult);
```

The code above will create the expected array format you described:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Email
            [type] => column
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16,23
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Web
            [type] => column
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 17
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: There were no reference on apexcharts from php & mysql on this topic.God bless you .Thank you man.

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the right answer please mark this as the correct answer.